# Problems with Samba member server, AD-DC and MMC

Tags: samba, mmc, rsat

I have 3 specific problems: the first, with the choice of id mapping, the second with the usermap from root to administrator, and the third with remote administration from a windows 10 computer using MMC and RSAT.

The first one, I tried to use 'ad' backend, but on the member server I don't see the users/groups created in the domain, so I can't set permissions on the shared folders. When I switch to the 'rid' backend, I can see the users/groups, but the ids of these are different from the ones defined in the ad-dc server and for this reason a user receives an authentication error when trying to access a resource for him. which -in theory- has the permissions set correctly.

Secondly, in my smb.conf file I set the line 'usermap = /path/to/user.map' and in that file I put the line "!root = Administrator", but when I try to connect to this server from the MMC console , it won't let me connect, if I comment that line, I can connect and see the shared resources.

Regardless of the above, my third problem is when I try to remotely manage (from MMC) the member server, I get the error "The computer [name.domain] cannot be managed. Please check that the network path is correct..." and "enable the following rules in the firewall: COM+ Network Access (DCOM Inbound)".

I am making this query after making several attempts with samba as AD-DC; after reading multiple manuals and answers in forums and not being able to solve my problems.
I am not new to linux and samba, but I am new to using samba as an active directory server and domain controller.

My apologies for the length of my question, this is my first time on this forum. Thank you in advance.